# php set cookie file_get_contents

Tags: php

Почему не работает?

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
            array(
                'email' => 'info@ya.ru',
                'password' => '3333'
            )
        );

        $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $postdata
            )
        );

        $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
        $result = file_get_contents('http://test.ru/loginshopuser.php', false, $context);
```

В loginshopuser.php:

```
setcookie("shopuseremail", $email, time()+60*999999, '/');
$_COOKIE["shopuseremail"] = $email;
setcookie("shopuserpassword", $password, time()+60*999999, '/');
$_COOKIE["shopuserpassword"] = $password;
```

На сайте куки не ставятся

Answer (score 0):

$_COOKIE["shopuseremail"] = $email; ничего вам не даст. В глобальную переменную $_COOKIE попадают cookie которые были переданы в http заголовке при запросе на сервер.
Функцию setcookie вы используете правильно - проверьте наличие куков в браузере с использую расширения firebug и подобные.